# Application launch error in Jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I receive an Application launch error whenever I launch Jupyter notebook.  I tried to follow the instructions in the last line of the error but the error never goes away.  Could it be something with the working directory?

When I check the working directory in Jupyter notebook using %pwd, I get C:\Users\mayerk

However, my Anaconda working directory is C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

This is the error that Anaconda Navigator returns each time I launch Jupyter Notebook:

```
[I 09:30:37.269 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.

[I 09:30:37.269 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.

[I 09:30:37.270 NotebookApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.

[I 09:30:37.324 NotebookApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab

[I 09:30:37.324 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab

[W 09:30:37.334 NotebookApp] Error loading server extension jupyterlab
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 321, in __init__
self._run(['node', 'node-version-check.js'], cwd=HERE, quiet=True)

File "C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 1165, in _run
proc = Process(cmd, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\process.py", line 73, in __init__
self.proc = self._create_process(cwd=cwd, env=env)

File "C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\process.py", line 131, in _create_process
cmd[0] = which(cmd[0], kwargs.get('env'))

File "C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\jlpmapp.py", line 59, in which
raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing installation. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1454, in init_server_extensions
func(self)

File "C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extension.py", line 111, in load_jupyter_server_extension
info = get_app_info(app_dir)

File "C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 244, in get_app_info
handler = _AppHandler(app_dir, logger)

File "C:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 324, in __init__
raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing installation. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.

[I 09:30:37.410 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\mayerk
[I 09:30:37.410 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 09:30:37.411 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 09:30:37.411 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8891/?token=fe440f0ea50e716458013d568b6f94f4a1c498959e39e490
[I 09:30:37.411 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:30:37.420 NotebookApp] 

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
http://localhost:8891/?token=fe440f0ea50e716458013d568b6f94f4a1c498959e39e490
[I 09:30:37.557 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
```

Answer (score 5):

> ValueError: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing
>   installation. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the
>   nodejs website.

Try: `conda install -y nodejs`

Comment: Thank you, Nehal.  How did you know this?

Comment: From this discussion: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/anaconda/sVyLkLRsWNg/JRJ3sCIECQAJ

Comment: Great!  Thank you, Nehal.  All the best.